# Docusign Integration

Tags: docusignapi

I can't see Recipients in view(ListStatusChange), just the list of envelopes.
when I write (model.Recipients.Signers.First().Name) returns null
Just I can see model.envelopeId, Status, StatusDateChange. I passed the model IEnumerable (Envelope)
I used templates for send my documents, here is the envelope definition:

```
public void GenerateDocument(string name, string email)
        {        
            var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient();
            var accountId = docuSignClient.LoginApi(username, password, integratorkey);

          var templateRoles = templateRoleNames.Select(m => new TemplateRole
            {
                Email = email,
                Name = name,
                RoleName = m
            }).ToList();

            var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                EmailSubject = subject,
                EmailBlurb = messageBody,
                TemplateId = templateId,
                TemplateRoles = templateRoles,
                Status = "sent"
            };
            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            var envelopesSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include recipients in the options for the [ListStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/) request.

You didn't show this code, but here is what it may look like:

```
    var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        ListStatusChangesOptions options = new ListStatusChangesOptions { include = "recipients" };
    options.fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    // Call the API method:
    EnvelopesInformation results = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
    return results;
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! @Inbar Gazit